# What does the term "Boardroom poker" mean?

Tags: terminology, board-of-directors

It seems to crop up occasionally, see for example this **[Wellington Fund blog post](http://www.wellingtonfund.com/blog/2011/12/27/not-so-fast-easyhome/#axzz1hxJiVFh6)** that uses the phrase:

> It is not time for high-stakes **Boardroom poker**, but that’s exactly
>   what happened at easyhome (EH:TSX)... At least I assume that some
>   **Boardroom poker** took place, since a majority of the easyhome Board of Directors resigned simultaneously, including one Director that had
>   been there for merely eight weeks. According to the press release,
>   five of the nine directors just up-and-left, leaving two independents,
>   a 29% shareholder Chairman and a CEO/Director to manage the affairs of
>   the company.

What does **Boardroom poker** usually mean?

Comment: I assume this had something to may a power play like a bluff in poker but the boss knew he had the best hand.  So in the end the losing hands were out.  But I do not think there is a "Common" use of the term.

Comment: "Do it our way or we resign." ... "There's the door."  ... "So be it, I quit" ... "I quit" ... "I quit" ... "Anyone else? No? Ok, shall we get to business?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intended use involves the power plays that occur amongst the senior officers of a company as they jockey for position through mergers, board control, takeovers, and other activities that are unique to the executive realm.  A lot of this certainly involves holding your hand close and revealing information strategically and deliberately if it furthers your cause.  And I'm sure there's a lot of bluffing and folding (resignations).

With regard to that article you posted, it's also appears to be a bit of a mystery from the outside looking in, because only the people playing know the rules.

A more pedestrian use of the term is an actual poker match with a high buy-in -- presumably high enough that only CEOs would have this kind of money to throw away.

Comment: Good answer. Definitely a mystery, and lots of bluffing and folding in that article! I've never read anything like that, when so many board of directors departed simultaneously.